# Unable to Erase External Hard Drive - Unable to lookup the APFS Container Reference

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, external-disk

I have an external hard drive that I put a linux operating ISO on, but now I am trying to erase the external back into ExFat format to store files on it. When I go into DiskUtil, and try to erase it, it just tells me the process failed.

I then went through the steps of trying to delete the APFS Container, I find the identifier using `diskutil list` then typing `diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk2s2`. It then just gives me a message that it is unable to find the reference to the container `Unable to look up the APFS Container Reference for the given Physical Store`.

I cannot find anything online on how to get this back to a state I can use it, any advice?

Comment: If you put Linux on it, it's not going to have an apfs container. And if it did, I'm pretty sure you could just use diskutil to erase the disk entirely.

Comment: When you want to erase the drive, what parameters do you select in disk utility?